# Boundedness on an open interval

Tags: calculus

Boundedness Theorem can be applied to a closed bounded interval. Now suppose on interval $(0, 1]$, continuous function $f(x)$ has a finite limit at $x\to 0+$, and is also finite at $x=1$. It seems that $f(x)$ is bounded. But how to formally prove or if the assertion is not valid?

Comment: Extend the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rigourous proof using epsilon-delta is as follows:

First define $$L := \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) < \infty.$$

Now fix an $\varepsilon >0$. By the definition of a limit, we can find a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x|<\delta$ for $x\in (0,1]$, then $|f(x) - L|<\varepsilon$.

As $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on the closed bounded interval $[\delta,1]$, by an $M>0$. Putting these two facts together gives
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,1]}|f(x)| \leq \sup_{x\in(0,\delta)}|f(x)|  + \sup_{x\in[\delta,1]}|f(x)| 
\leq L + \varepsilon + M.$$

This implies $f$ is bounded on $(0,1]$.